# Why this 404 error coming while running nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I'm new to nodejs and express and when I run the webserver inside `localhost:3000` it works fine, but when I uploaded it to GitHub, a bunch of 404 errors popped up :(.

I have a shopping cart site with [stripe](https://stripe.com/) payment platform

Sorry for any worthless information. I just started learning the language for couple months, and would be more then happy to get any help with the 404 crappy errors:/

---

server.js code

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
const stripePublicKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey)
const path = require('path')




app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      res.render('store.ejs', {
        stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
        items: JSON.parse(data)
      })
    }
  })
})

app.post('/purchase', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      const itemsJson = JSON.parse(data)
      const itemsArray = itemsJson.music.concat(itemsJson.merch)
      let total = 0
      req.body.items.forEach(function(item) {
        const itemJson = itemsArray.find(function(i) {
          return i.id == item.id
        })
        total = total + itemJson.price * item.quantity
      })


      stripe.charges.create({
        amount: total,
        source: req.body.stripeTokenId,
        currency: "ils",

      }).then(function() {
        console.log('Charge Successful')
        res.json({ message: 'Successfully purchased items' })
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Charge Fail')
        res.status(500).end()
      })
    }
  })
})


app.listen(3000)
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "current-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "heroku": "^7.39.3",
    "stripe": "^6.36.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

store.ejs code>>>>

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Generics | Store</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        data-key="pk_test_Bw3njISkUtVgbdP0ClLHa5fi00TTeF0KGP"
        ></script> 
        <script>
            var stripePublicKey = '<%= stripePublicKey %>'
        </script>
        <script src="store.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./store">STORE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="band-name band-name-large">The Generics</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <% items.music.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
                        <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
                        <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/<%= item.imgName %>">
                        <div class="shop-item-details">
                            <span class="shop-item-price">₪<%= item.price / 100 %></span>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">MERCH</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <% items.merch.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
                        <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
                        <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/<%= item.imgName %>">
                        <div class="shop-item-details">
                            <span class="shop-item-price">₪<%= item.price / 100 %></span>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">₪0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
        </section>
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <div class="container main-footer-container">
                <h3 class="band-name">The Generics</h3>
                <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/YouTube Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.spotify.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Spotify Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="Images/Facebook Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and store.js

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
}
```

Comment: Can you actually share part of the stack trace of the error thrown?

Comment: actually i think my server.js dont respond so i cant acces the store.ejs